# What is the different between these two ways for declaring variables in python?

Tags: python

While printing fibonacci Series

```
a,b,c=1,1,1
while (c<7):
  print(b,end=" ")
  a,b,c=b,b+1,c+1
```

the output is >> 1 2 3 5 8 13

and when I was tracing the code I found the result is >> 1 2 4 8 16 32

this output resulted by declaring the variables in this way

```
a,b,c=1,1,1
while (c<7):
  print(b,end=" ")
  a=b
  b=a+b
  c=c+1
```

So what is the difference between these two different ways in declaring the variables

Comment: You don't want to use the former if the variables depend upon each other.

Comment: Well, one big difference is that the second way, you wrote `b=a+b` instead of assigning `b+1` to `b`.

Comment: Actually, I think you meant to use `a+b` in the first version, too. You probably retyped the code into the question box and mixed it up. If you'd actually used `b+1`, you wouldn't have gotten that output. This is why we have copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
a,b,c=b,a+b,c+1
```

is equivalent to:

```
new_a = b
new_b = a + b
new_c = c + 1

a = new_a
b = new_b
c = new_c
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that when you say:

```
  a,b,c=b,b+1,c+1
```

the rhs of `=` is evaluated and then the values are assigned to the variables on the lhs.

This would work ok as long as the assignments do not have a side-effect on the subsequent ones.  For example:

```
a=42
b=7+a
c=b-a
```

isn't the same as

```
a, b, c = 42, 7+a, b-a
```

If a, b, c were all set to 0 then in the first case you'd end up with 42, 49, 7 respectively.  Whereas in the second case, you'd get 42, 7, 0

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in your first example is called "tuple assignment".

Python first constructs the tuple `(b, b+1, c+1)`, and then pairwise assigns each value to its corresponding variable.

it's a more pythonic way for assignment.